# Windows PuTTY - git error - No supported authentication methods

Tags: git, ssh, putty

I don't have this problem when I use git locally on my machine, ONLY when logged in via SSH with PuTTY. FYI my server is using freeSSHd.

Assuming my current directory is my git repository's local directory...

The command `git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin` issues the following error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
```

Again, this only happens when I'm logged in via PuTTY and not when I'm in the command prompt when I'm physically at the server.

Comment: will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294381/google-server-putty-connect-disconnected-no-supported-authentication-methods-a or this one? http://askubuntu.com/questions/204400/ssh-public-key-no-supported-authentication-methods-available-server-sent-publ

Comment: No, I don't have any problems connecting to freeSSHd. The problem is that once I've logged in and try and exectute a git pull command, I get that error. So it's like there's an "environment difference" between being actually logged in to the computer and logged in over SSH that's causing the conflict. Somehow the git command isn't reading the right private ssh key or something?

Comment: And just to confirm that you login as the same person locally and remotely :) ? Can you run this command - `cksum ~/.ssh/*` locally and remotely to ensure checksums are the same. Furthermore, can you run this command remotely via [tag:Putty] `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, the `id_rsa` should be replaced by whatever your `.ssh` key is called. Then run your [tag:git] command with `--verbose`

Comment: I'm using Windows by the way - hence the need for freeSSHd. I can't run a cksum command. If there's an alternative command I can run through the command prompt to give you what you need I'll do it. And yes, I'm logging in with the same username - Administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pageant.exe is inaccessible to Administrator logged in via SSH even though it's accessible to Administrator normally. I had to invoke pageant while inside SSH to get it to work; this results in multiple pageant.exe processes :( In the end I ditched freeSSHd for cygwin and now I have another set of problems.