# Disconnected : No supported authentication methods available (server sent :publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to Amazon EC2 and trying to configure it. I have created the instances and trying to connect. I am getting the error as "Disconnected : No supported authentication methods available (server sent :publickey)".

I have got the keypair from EC2 Management console and have used putty gen to generate private key file(PPK).

Kindly assist to resolve.

I have already referred [Google server putty connect 'Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294381/google-server-putty-connect-disconnected-no-supported-authentication-methods-a)  but couldn't get my problem resolved.[image: Error screen]

Comment: Which Linux distribution?

Comment: Your login may not be ec2-user. It can vary depending on AMI.

Comment: @DavidLevesque : Ubuntu Linux - 64 Bit

Comment: @datasage : Thanks a lot.I have tried Amazon linux instance and have used ec2-user as user name.Getting logged in. But I am unable to access my public IP from my browser.

Comment: @RameshJothimani In that case you need to make sure you have a web server running and port 80 is open.

Comment: Thanks @datasage .That was the issue.I have added a rule and it works.

Comment: @RameshJothimani How to add Ip to security groups for SSH connection

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For the record, the usual default username in EC2 for these Linux distro:

- Amazon Linux: *ec2-user*
- Ubuntu: *ubuntu*
- Debian : *admin*

To access the instance through a browser, make sure you [add a rule in your security group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/computebasics/getting-started-security-group.html) to allow port 80 and port 443 inbound.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same problem on Amazon EC2 and I simply changed my username to "ubuntu" and it made a connection.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem even with **ec2-user**, I used **Public DNS** instead of **Public IP**. It resolved now.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16528645)

Comment: @iehrlich, I never said "thank you". which one you referring to?

Comment: I had this issue when I restarted the instance. I had a elastic ip which I removed before I restarted. And then to resolve the issue I used Public DNS

Answer (score 2):

Use the public dns name instead of IP.
In the putty, choose connection > SSH > Auth.
You will see the Authentication Parameter part,
in there you can choose your ppk file.

And one more very important thing.
Click the "Allow attempted changes of username in SSH-2" to activate it.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand that if your instance is created by any any other service (like Elastic Beanstalk) and not directly from EC2, you are likely to face similar problems.

It is possible the there is **no Key pair associated with your instance** yet. To validate this go to your instance from

> EC2 dashboard > Description

Look out for '**Key pair name**' there. If there is a valid value there (this must the same you used to generate the key from Putty Key Generator) then this suspicion can be overruled. Otherwise you may need to recreate instance as a worst case scenario.

In my case, the instance was create by Elastic Beanstalk i.e. EBS (another AWS service) where I hosted a web application, I attached an existing key pair to the EBS environment and the connection through Putty went through.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem,*resolved* using the correct `username` and loading `.ppk` file properly.

Username in EC2 varies depending upon AMI machine, Use following logins on following AMIs:

`ubuntu or root on ubuntu AMIs
ec2-user on Amazon Linux AMI
centos on Centos AMI
debian or root on Debian AMIs
ec2-user or fedora on Fedora
ec2-user or root on: RHEL AMI, SUSE AMI, other ones.`

If you are using OS:

`Windows - get PEM key from AWS website and generate PPK file using PuttyGen. Then use Putty to use the PPK (select it using left-column: Connection->SSH->Auth: Private key for authorization)`

`Linux - run: ssh -i your-ssh-key.pem login@IP-or-DNS`

Find Full Documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html)  and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectingPuTTY)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Issue but the reason I was getting the error is because I gave a different kevaluepair name when I created an Instance to what I'm using.

Make sure that the key value pair name is same across all situations.