# permission denied to transfer file from my computer to EC2 with scp command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The instance is launched and I can connect perfectly from my computer. However when I am trying to upload a file to ec2 using the following command:

scp -r -i key.pem path/file ec2-54-195-205-200.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/media/ephemeral0/

I have always the following error:
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection

Comment: it is not a permission file problem. Already tried chmod 777 path

Answer (score 1):

The username seems to be missing in your scp command. Try adding it before the remote host, separated by a `@`. For example, with username `admin`:

```
scp -r -i key.pem path/file admin@ec2-54-195-205-200.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/media/ephemeral0/
```

The default username in EC2 varies depending on the OS. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21545251/1464763) for some hints.